# How to use Oracle code in Firebird

Tags: oracle, firebird-3.0

Oracle's `alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-YYYY'`, how do i use that in firebird?

I tried casting but it does not work and extract and I can't get it work.

Comment: Oracle code that requires `alter session set nls_date_format` is broken to begin with because it relies on the evil implicit data type conversion.

Comment: Also: [edit] your question and add the code that you have problem with and the **exact** error message you get

Comment: You can't just map Oracle functionality to Firebird. Please describe what you are trying to achieve, so we can give you a real solution.